# when using zc.buildout encounter a "UserWarning" about double import pkg_resources

Tags: python, buildout

when I run `bin/buildout` , the warning repeated like this:

```
/Users/healdream/Playground/python/buildout/parts/buildout/site.py:262: UserWarning: Module pkg_resources was already imported from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py, but /Users/healdream/Playground/python/buildout/eggs/distribute-0.6.19-py2.6.egg is being added to sys.path
  import pkg_resources
```

I use zope's [bootstrap.py](http://svn.zope.org/%2acheckout%2a/zc.buildout/trunk/bootstrap/bootstrap.py) and before run `bin/buildout`, I run `python bootstrap.py --distribute`

in bootstrap.py, `pkg_resources` is imported, and in bin/buildout `parts/buildout` is prepended to sys.path

```
sys.path[0:0] = [
    '/Users/healdream/Playground/python/buildout/parts/buildout',
    ]
```

in parts/buildout/site.py:262, pkg_resources is explicitly imported again `import pkg_resources`. so the warning appears.

how to avoid the warning?

Comment: finally figured out by upgrade python to 2.6.7

Answer (score 0):

It was probably a isolation issue which was only addressed by the upgrade because it replaced the base installation.  If it happens again, trying a virtualenv is a good idea:

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages .
$ bin/python bootstrap.py
$ bin/buildout
```